# Improve the speed of large collection querying

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

Querying in the collection which contains 3 million items (collection size is `15GB`).

```
//indexing
{name : 1}

//query
db.getCollection('contacts').find({name :"kello"}).limit(500)
```

The machine has `2Cores` and `8GB` memory, and it takes about **30 seconds** to finish this query. It is impossible to keep your client waiting for about half minutes.

What can I do to accelerate it?

Does it work to have a machine which contains 16GB/32GB memory and configure the mongodb to cache the whole collection into memory, so that it can finish the query all in memory?

Or, should I got several 8GB machines to have a sharded cluster?

Will those methods improve the query speed?

Comment: This looks verry strange for such a query. Which version of Mongodb are you using? With which engine ? Can you also post the explain of this query?

Comment: 3.0 for now. MMAP. It is just an example to search on an indexed key (i.e. `name` here).

Comment: You should first upgrade your mongoDB version (current is 3.4) and switch to WiredTiger to take full advantage of data compression. Then make sure that network speed is not the bottleneck. If the problem persists, you'll need to take a look at the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/). Before thinking of sharding/ upgrading hardware, make sure you know where the problem comes from

Comment: How big are the documents in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can create index to search documents to get faster response. You can also use elastic search to get quicker response.

https://www.compose.com/articles/mongoosastic-the-power-of-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-together/

Comment: We have created the indexs, but it is still slow. Elastic search consume more memory than we thought.